# with socat, given port on the remote (server) host is to be forwarded to the given host and port on the local side

Tags: port-forwarding, socat

Is it possible to use socat to achieve the following, without the need of using ssh?

```
> ssh -N -R 8080:localhost:1080 mylogin@server.com

-R [bind_address:]port:host:hostport
  Specifies that the given port on the remote (server) host is to be forwarded to the given host and port on the local side.
  This works by allocating a socket to listen to port on the remote side, and whenever a connection is made to this port, 
  the connection is forwarded over the secure channel, and a connection is made to host port hostport from the local machine.

-N  Do not execute a remote command.  This is useful for just forwarding ports (protocol version 2 only).
```

Comment: hey i need this answer

Answer (score 0):

Probably not.  While `socat` can certainly forward port 8080 on your local system to port 1080 on the remote system, it can't change your point of origin -- you'll still be connecting from your local system.

Using ssh, the connection is forwarded over an ssh tunnel such that when something connects to port 1080 on the remote system, it appears to be originating on that system as well.  This has substantial implications if there are firewalls preventing external access to that port (or if the corresponding process is only listening on the loopback interface).